# searchview does not show any results

Tags: java, android, searchview

I am trying to get a search results from a custom adapter which does not show any results. The list view is working, but when I search or type any word in the search view nothing happens. Could somebody help me doing the things.

```
    Mainactivity.java

    package com.studiored.muslimbabynames;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView boy, girl;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            girl = findViewById(R.id.girlimage);
            boy = findViewById(R.id.boyimage);


            girl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GirlName.class);
                startActivity(i);
                }
            });
            boy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BoyName.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        }
    }


    BoyName.java
    package com.studiored.muslimbabynames;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuInflater;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.SearchView;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class BoyName extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView List_itemboy;
    NameAdapter adapter;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_boy_name);

            ArrayList<NameListClass> nameList = new ArrayList<NameListClass>();

            nameList.add(new NameListClass("Rayyan", "Door of a Paradise"));
            nameList.add(new NameListClass("Rafi", "Best Friend"));
            nameList.add(new NameListClass("Sadiq", "Sadiq"));
            nameList.add(new NameListClass("Rayyan", "Door of a Paradise"));
            nameList.add(new NameListClass("Rayyan", "Door of a Paradise"));
            nameList.add(new NameListClass("Rayyan", "Door of a Paradise"));
            nameList.add(new NameListClass("Rayyan", "Door of a Paradise"));
            nameList.add(new NameListClass("Rayyan", "Door of a Paradise"));
            nameList.add(new NameListClass("Rayyan", "Door of a Paradise"));
            nameList.add(new NameListClass("Rayyan", "Door of a Paradise"));


             adapter = new NameAdapter(this, nameList);
            List_itemboy = findViewById(R.id.list_itemboy);
            List_itemboy.setAdapter(adapter);
            List_itemboy.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
            MenuInflater inflater =getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_view,menu);
            MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search_name);
            SearchView searchView = (SearchView)item.getActionView();
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

                    return false;
                }
            });
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }

    }
```

This is my custom Adapter file
        NameAdapter.java

```
    package com.studiored.muslimbabynames;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import org.w3c.dom.Text;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class NameAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NameListClass> {

        public NameAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<NameListClass> nameList) {
            super(context, 0, nameList);


        }
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
            NameListClass name = getItem(position);
            if (convertView == null){
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_view,parent,false);
            }
            TextView Listname = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            Listname.setText(name.Name);
            TextView MeanigName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            MeanigName.setText(name.Meaning);
            return convertView;
        }


    }
```

This is the customclass
        NameListClass.java

```
    package com.studiored.muslimbabynames;

    import java.security.PublicKey;

    public class NameListClass {
        public String Name;
        public String Meaning;

        public NameListClass(String babyname, String babynamemeaning){
            Name = babyname;
            Meaning = babynamemeaning;

        }
    }


xml file of Boy name activity
    BoyName.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".BoyName">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="50dp">
            <TextView

                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Name" />

            <TextView
                android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"

                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Meaning" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/list_itemboy"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    list_view_item.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    >

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:text="Name"
        />

    <TextView
        android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"

        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Meaning" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I dont see any filter in your adapter class.

Answer (score 1):

On Text change put this code

```
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
            String newText = query.toLowerCase();
            ArrayList<NameListClass> newList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (NameListClass r : nameList){
                String name = r.getOwner();
                if (name.contains(newText)){
                    newList.add(r);
                }
            }
            retailerAdapter.setFilter(newList);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

And in Your Adapter do this..

```
 public void setFilter(ArrayList<NameListClass> newList){
    nameList= new ArrayList<>();
    nameList.addAll(newList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Thank yout.. But I dont understand what is that retailerAdapter. Is that my custom adapter? Also the the gerOwner() function. Please be in detail..

Comment: retailerAdapter is my custom Adapter Object and getOwner is my model class method which return string..
Please accept answer if its help

Comment: I made the following changes to the  code. Actually it does show the filtered names in the log. but it does not show any filtered list in the search view..

Comment: whats the problem ? @RAFI

Comment: I made the changes to the code. Actually it does show the filtered names in the log. but it does not show any filtered list in the search view. @ Faiz Mir.

Comment: Where you are trying to show the search result in recyleview or listview ?

Comment: I suggest you to use Recylerview